# Alterar dominio de um site

Tags: wordpress, domínio

Quando comecei a fazer o meu site utilizei o dominio **.atspace.eu** por ser gratuito. Agora que já conclui o site, gostava de passa-lo para **.pt** .

O site foi desenvolvido em wordpress.

Alguém consegue ajudar-me a fazer esta tranferência de dominios?

Obrigado

Comment: A unica coisa que posso te ajudar é dizer que o WP da problema quando muda a url, vai precisar dar um search & replace no banco para atualizar as URLs. Se nao fizer isso quando estiver no site atspace.pt vai acabar redirecionando para atspace.eu. Isso por que as URLs ficam salvas no banco. Uma ferramenta bem legal para gerenciar o wp é o [wp-cli](http://wp-cli.org/)

Comment: existe [um guia de migração](https://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress) pra evitar os problemas citados no comentário do @NeuberOliveira.

Comment: @CaioFelipePereira nunca tinha ouvido falar desse guia, muito bom, favoritado ja valeu!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bom, na parte de wordpress é tranquilo, no próprio painel você muda o domínio tranquilamente, visto que ele vai fazer tudo automaticamente, até mesmo atualizar as urls do banco de dados:

[image: Pelo próprio painel você pode mudar o domínio do site]

Pelo próprio painel você pode mudar o domínio do site.

Agora o maior problema na minha opinião é SE a hospedagem tem recursos para troca de domínio, ou seja, se lá no painel deles (host) tem a opção mudar o dominio parecido com o do wordpress, caso sim ai é tranquilo. Atualize lá e o no wordpress e seja feliz.

Boa sorte.